# Is there any way to merge a Countif formula with an Index(Max) formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a file for Pokémon trading online where people can search for Pokémon from others active players. They are typing a Pokémon name and got the name of the player who has one to exchange and informations about the Pokémon.
In particular, when they are looking for a Pokémon, the search goes to every Pokémon that are in the same family (Bulbasaur, Ivysaur and Venusaur for exemple) using the Pokédex number of the family.

I'm trying to merge two of my formula to get ride of one column.
One of my formula give me a Pokédex number depending on the name of the Pokémon. (i.e. I have a Pokémon name and I retrive his Pokédex number in a column). This formula is pasted on all the column comparing with the cell next to his for each line.

The second of my formula, give me intel of a Pokémon line regarding a research cell by comparing the Pokédex number with the column that calculate it (with the first formula).

First fomula :

> =ArrayFormula(INDEX(PokedexNumberColumn;MAX(IF(PokemonNameColumn=PokemonNameToCopareCell;ROW(PokedexNumberColumn)))))

Second formula :

> =IF(COUNTIF(Formula1Column;ResearchCell)>COUNTIF(CellsBelowTheCurrentCell;"PlayerName");HYPERLINK("SheetLink";"PlayerName");"")

So like I said, the first formula is a cell to cell formula in which I got the Pokedex Family Number for the Pokemon in the line.

The second one is a bit more complex, I count how many time the research cell is in the player sheet and compare it with the amount I already displayed. If I need more diplay, I put it. If not, nothing.

What I expected is to merge the two formula to be able to get ride of the column with the first formula, because the file is shared online and often people damaged the formula by adding or deleting some lines.

EDIT : I create a file simplified of my problem : https://transfernow.net/ddl/PokemonLists
In the Search Option Tab we have:
In Blue, you have the cell of research where you choose the name of the Pokemon you're looking for. In Orange are the formula I used, first the family number of the Pokemon searched in order to look for any other Pokemon of the same family. And then the two others cells in orange are just the results.
In the Pokedex Tab we have only intels to which make reference when we're making a research, name of Pokemon and Family Numbers.
In Player1 Tab, we have the list of Pokemon that the player one can exchange, with in Orange the famous Formula I want to erase by putting it directly in the first Tab Formula. This formula goes into the Pokedex Tab to find the Family Number of the Pokemon and display it.

So if you're going into the first Tab and select a Pokemon in the blue cell, you will have a result if the pokemon or one of its family is in the list of the player one. It's the case for option 4 to 9, not 1, 2 and 3.
I don't care about merge formula of the first tab as it's always protected except the search cell. What I need is to erase the formula of the player tab in order to avoid problem when they add or delete lines.

Thank you !

Comment: Please add sample data with expected output. Right now all I can say it's probably possible.

Comment: I'm preparing a file with the only necessary formula I used. I'm working on Googlesheet, so I need time to convert the file into a exportable excel :)

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand the question. A pokemon is selected in `B1`, and you want to know if player 1 has a pokemon to trade that falls in the same family number?

Comment: Yes that's it ! But to make the comparaison with the family number, I create a formula in the player Tab that I would like to merge in the Search Tab to avoid any grief of the formula when I share the payer tab to the player.